# How to extract last word in richtextbox in c#

Tags: c#, cpu-word, richtextbox, extract

I am working with windows form. In my project i need to color the last word of rich text box. When someone write on the given text box of the application i need the last word that is just written on the richtextbox to be colored red or whatever.

I found a way to extract the last word from the following link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.textselection.select%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

But i need more handy code to extract the last word if its possible. Please help.

Comment: The code you supplied seems very straightforward.

Comment: Have you tried that code?  Looks good. What needs to be better about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the sample code

*> char[] arr = new char[50];

> ```
>       int i = 0;
>     private void richTextBox1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
>      {
>     if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)            {
>         string str = new string(arr); 
>         MessageBox.Show(str);
>         Array.Clear(arr, 0, arr.Length);
>         i = 0;
>     }
>     else if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Back)
>        {
>         i--;
>         if (i < 0)
>         {
>             i = 0;
>         }
>         arr[i] = ' ';
>
>
>     }
>
>     else
>     {
>         arr[i] = (char)e.KeyValue;
>
>         i++;
>     }
>     }*
> ```

This is how you will be able to extract the latest word. Now color yourself the word you like.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you really are just looking to get the last word, you could do something like this...Assuming of course, that you make a string equal to the text of your rich text box.

```
string str="hello, how are you doing?";
if (str.Length >0)
{
    int index=str.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1;
    str = str.Substring(index));
}
```

Then just return the string, and do what you need to do with it.

Comment: This won't help him color that word, and also won't work if the last word is in a paragraph of its own.

Comment: how does this have anything to do with a rich text box in c#

Answer (score -1):

As I remember rich text box can render text as HTML.
Just wrap your last word in font tag and that's it.

Comment: extract the last word is the question, not how to color a word